# how to set a border color to a masked UIView swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I used the following function I got from SO to create diamond shaped UIViews:

```
func addDiamondMaskToView(view: UIView) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: view.bounds.size.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
        path.closePath()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
```

But when I use the following code to create a border around it, you can only see the very edges of the diamond, because for some reason the old square shape is blocking it

```
            testView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            testView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            testView2.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            testView2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            testView3.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            testView3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

            addDiamondMaskToView(testView)
            addDiamondMaskToView(testView2)
            addDiamondMaskToView(testView3)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use CAShapeLayer(), so you no need too add view with border. just custom only CAShapeLayer() it's enough.

```
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
```

try this with your CAShapeLayer()